# Error en django api en Models | "Reverse query name for 'ModelA.id_user' clashes with reverse query name for 'ModelB.usuario'."

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, djangorestframework

En mi `models.py` tengo estos modelos:

```py
class Usuario(AbstractUser):

    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="testname")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="test_lastname")
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="username")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['id_user', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'usuario'


class ConfiguracionCv(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        Usuario, related_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bloque = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    atributo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ordenCompleto = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordenResumido = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    visible_cv_resumido = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    visible_cv_completo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mapeo = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["bloque", "atributo"] 
        db_table = 'configuracionCV'
        

class ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, related_name='Usuario',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bloque = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    atributo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    orden = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    visible_cv_personalizado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mapeo = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cv = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nombre_cv = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="personalizado_cv")
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    cedula = models.TextField(max_length=11)
    nombreBloque = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Articulos")
    ordenPersonalizable = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    visible_cv_bloque = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["bloque", "atributo", "nombre_cv", "cedula"] 
        db_table = 'configuracioncvPersonalizado'
```

Cuando intento hacer el `makemigrations` recibo este error:

```
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario' or 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user'.
cv_api.ConfiguracionCv.usuario: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario' clashes with reverse query name for 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario' or 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user'.
cv_api.ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user' or 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario'.
cv_api.ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user' clashes with reverse query name for 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.id_user' or 'ConfiguracionCv.usuario'.
```

Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay un conflicto con la relación inversa en ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado y  ConfiguracionCv.

El atributo **related_name** del campo del modelo define la relación inversa de un modelo, entonces cuando accedes a un objeto Usuario.objects.get().**related_name** el irá al modelo que tenga ese **related_name**, como tienes los dos con el mismo nombre el no sabría para donde ir por eso la migración te da el error.

Te recomiendo colocar el **related_name** con un nombre referencial al modelo:

```
class ConfiguracionCv(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
    Usuario, related_name='ConfiguracionCv', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

entonces si quieres acceder a la ConfiguracionCv del usuario id=1 sería asi:

```
conf_cv_queryset = Usuario.objects.get(id=1).ConfiguracionCv.all()
```

Nota: colocando solo ConfiguracionCv traería el objeto relacional, colocalndole el **.all()** tratería un queryset de todas las ConfiguracionesCv relacionados con ese usuario

si quieres filtrar aquellos usuarios que tengan una configuracioncv con una instancia dada

```
#obtengo la primera instancia del queryset
conf_cv = conf_cv_queryset.first()
Usuario.objects.filter(ConfiguracionCv=conf_cv)
#usando el id
Usuario.objects.filter(ConfiguracionCv__id=conf_cv.id)
```